# Max User Connection issue with Hibernate and Java

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am using following code for database connection with Hibernate and Java specified in my applicationcontext file,

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />    
    <property name="user" value="admin" />  
    <property name="password" value="pass" />   
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="10" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />        
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="120" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="1" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
  </bean>
```

on the server after sometime it gives following error

> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
> WARNING:
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@198c333 --
>
> Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying
> to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the
> maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
> Last acquisition attempt exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User admin already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

can anyone let me know where I m going wrong

Comment: This may be helpful http://www.coderanch.com/t/216073/ORM/databases/HowTo-configure-properties-hibernateconfig-xml

Comment: I have this same problem. C3P0 eats all of my available connections and brings down my DB.

Comment: You can have a connection leak issue, you can also try with different connection pooling as Hikari

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a configuration problem with your database. It's likely that your database couldn't let to the same user 10 simultanious connections. Maybe you could try to reduce `maxPoolSize` and `minPoolSize` to 1 so you can see your real problem.(Since the exception that you see is  just the last exception given)

Answer (score -1):

Take a loot at these urls:

[How To Configure DBCP Connection Pool In Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-dbcp-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)

[How To Configure The C3P0 Connection Pool In Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)

Hope it helps.